# QSystemTrayIcon not available then run application with sudo on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml, sudo

QSystemTrayIcon not available in application if run with sudo. How can this problem be solved?

```
./qsystemtrayicontest        - the tray icon is available
sudo ./qsystemtrayicontest   - the tray icon is not available
```

output

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'

ERROR: No native SystemTrayIcon implementation available.
Qt Labs Platform requires Qt Widgets on this setup.
Add 'QT  = widgets' to .pro and create QApplication in main().

qml: SystemTrayIcon::available false
```

Below is a minimal example with a qml interface. But on ordinary widget error is repeated in the same way.

**qsystemtrayicontest.pro**

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11
QT += widgets
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
        if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
            return -1;

        return app.exec();
    }
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "SystemTrayIcon::available: " + idSystemTrayIcon.available
    }

    SystemTrayIcon {
        id: idSystemTrayIcon
        visible: true
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("SystemTrayIcon::available", available)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);` to `QApplication app(argc, argv);`

Comment: After the transition to the QApplication error message about widgets are gone from the console. But the tray icon continues to be unavailable.

Comment: Maybe you've installed Qt locally, in the user's home folder?

Comment: Yes, I have several Qt assemblies installed in the user's home folder. Including Qt builds made on this machine. I would like to solve the problem without having to install qt in the system directories. It is planned to distribute the program in one catalog (bundle).